# Oracle Iterate query result without insert

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following table like below

[image]

And the result I expected below, depend on the date diff (ex. 2020/3/27 - 2020/3/20 =7) and extend the result. Does it possible without use insert to the internal table and extend the table by the original. Because of the privilege limitation.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it possible without use insert to the internal table and extend
>   the table by the original. Because of the privilege limitation.

Yes it possible using `Level` in SQL statement. See below

```
SELECT
  SYSDATE - level
 ,'XXX' Name
 ,10  QTY
 ,level Date_diff
from
  dual
connect by
  level < 8
order by
  1;
```

EDIT: As per sample data given, the query is modified as

```
With       
      tab1 as  (  --Implementing Logic    
                  Select 
                        v_date - (level-1) v_date ,
                         name,
                         qty,
                        (data_diff+1) - level col
                  from tab            
                  connect by level <= data_diff                      
                )
   -- Selecting records
   select distinct * 
   from tab1 
   order by name,col desc ;
```

Demo:

```
With Tab(v_date,name,qty,data_diff)
        as ( -- Table Data
             select to_date('20-Mar-2020','DD-Mon-YYYY'),'A',10, 7 from dual
             UNION 
             select to_date('29-Mar-2020','DD-Mon-YYYY'),'B',12, 3 from dual
             UNION ALL
             select to_date('17-Mar-2020','DD-Mon-YYYY'),'C',30, 4 from dual
            ),    
      tab1 as  (      
                  Select 
                        v_date - (level-1) v_date ,
                         name,
                         qty,
                        (data_diff+1) - level col
                  from tab            
                  connect by level <= data_diff                      
                )

   select distinct * 
   from tab1 
   order by name,col desc ;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when I'm thinking about if there comes a lot of different Names(ex. XXX, YYY, etc..), how do I leveling the data by the group?

Comment: You can edit you question and put all the scenario so that i can modify my answer.

Comment: Hi Xing, thanks for your time review the issue, I updated the sample data above, do you have any idea leveling by the group['Name']?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, real helpful, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below

```
          WITH data
             AS (SELECT To_date('20-MAR-2020', 'DD-MON-YYYY') date1,
                        'xxx'                                 name,
                        10                                    qty,
                        7                                     date_diff
                 FROM   dual)
        SELECT date1 + LEVEL-1,
               name,
               qty,
               date_diff - LEVEL+1
        FROM   data
        CONNECT BY LEVEL < date_diff + 1
```

Comment: Isn't it same as what i posted below ? Also, this will miss one date range. Expected output will not be same as what OP wanted.

Comment: i have added union all to handle that case,also date1 should be incremented and date_diff should be decremented

Comment: `UNION ALL` is an overhead to the SQL. You can simply extend `Connect By` clause by `1` and and make your dataset start date `19-mar-2020`. However, this looks an duplicate answer to my answer.

Comment: i was able to do it without making the start date 19-mar-2020 and by simply extend Connect by clause by 1 as you mentioned

Comment: Your logic goes by SYSDATE where else my logic goes by user-provided date